# MySQL How To Get Top N Rows per Each Group

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I've research for the answer for a long time, I found a very good solution in a page, but I does not work well, I want to know why? The URL is: http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/how-to/get_top_n_each_group

I follow the method, here is my code:

```
SELECT id,  
type,
IF (@type = type, @type_rank + 1, 1) AS type_rank, 
@type := type 
FROM imagesforctool 
LIMIT 10
```

the results is :

```
    id      type    type_rank   @type := type
    192499  Men       1          Men
    192500  Men       1          Men
    192504  Men       1          Men
    192508  Men       1          Men
    192514  Men       1          Men
    192515  Men       1          Men
    192516  Men       1          Men
    192518  Men       1          Men
    192519  Men       1          Men
    192520  Men       1          Men
```

the `type_rank` column does not plus.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,  
type,
@type_rank:=IF (@type = type, @type_rank + 1, 1), 
@type := type 
FROM imagesforctool ORDER BY type
LIMIT 10
```

This is the correct query.
you need to assign value of `@type_rank`

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
  id,  
  type,
  @type_rank := IF(@current_type = type, @type_rank + 1, 1) AS type_rank,
  @current_type := type
FROM 
  imagesforctool 
ORDER BY
  type
LIMIT
  10
```